# How to get last entry by date

Tags: mysql

I have a table  exchange_rates with columns ( Id , currency, date , selling_rate).
Sample data :

| Id | currency | date | selling_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usd | 10/11/2021 | 80 |
| 2 | usd | 15/11/2021 | 82 |
| 3 | usd | 29/11/2021 | 81 |
| 4 | eur | 30/11/2021 | 95 |

I want to get last entered (by date) for usd selling_rate

```
$sql = " SELECT selling_rate 
         FROM   echange_rates 
         WHERE  currency=usd 
         ORDER BY date DESC 
         LIMIT 1
";
```

Result should be `81` (for usd latest entry is 29/11/2021)

Comment: Are you getting an error or just an incorrect result? Based on what you have here, you at least need quotes around usd, `'usd'`. You also have a typo in your table name, `exchange_rates`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your query using the table data you provided except I addded a couple of quotation marks for you `currency` column due to its string datatype. The answer I got is 81. I suppose you ran into a syntax error for that? 
By the way be careful with the `date` column you defined. By default, MySQL does not support dd/mon/year format naturally. Therefore, to adjust to your depicted data format, I used the varchar type. This is prone to mistakes when doing comparisons as the initial character value matters most. e.g. `insert into tb values (5,'usd','11/12/2021',84);`  The answer you get is still 81 rather than 84.
My suggestion is to use the `date` type for the column which is meant to be a date, then use `date_format` function to display it in the intended way. In this case , date_format(`date`,'%d/%m/%Y') will do the work.